# problema en Swift con el simulador

Tags: swift

Cuando quiero iniciar un simulador en Swift para ver mi aplicación me aparece un error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo no he cambiado el código.
Soy nuevo y no sé en que versión de Swift estoy, solo sé que estoy en la última versión de Xcode hasta el momento.
Gracias

Comment: Explica más el error, agrega el código (que no este en capturas) para ver donde esta el error, con una captura de pantalla de las primeras 30 lineas no podemos saber que esta pasando.

Answer (score 0):

El error te indica que no encuentra una celda con ese identificador *"CountryCell"*.

Si usas Storyboards debes hacer lo siguiente:

1. Selecciona el `TableView` y en el inspector de atributos verifica si tienes celdas dinámicas en 1.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2. Si lo tienes, selecciona la celda del `TableView` en el Storyboard.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3. Y nuevamente en el inspector de atributos verifica que el identificador tenga el nombre del error **"CountryCell"**. En este caso la celda se llama "cell".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si no usas Storyboards:

1. En el método `viewDidLoad` debes registrar la celda con ese nombre:

   ```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "CountryTableCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "CountryCell")
    }
   ```

Lo que hace el código es indicarle al `TableView` que tienes una celda creada de tipo `TableViewCell` con el nombre *"CountryTableCell"* y que tiene como identificador el nombre **"CountryCell"**.